# Play! Framework ошибка при загрузке сайта

Tags: java, веб-программирование, сервер, hibernate, playframework

Есть сайт, сделан на фреймворке Play. Поставили на серв, а оно выдает ошибку (Скрин). Я не знаю уже , что делать! Это мой первый проект, работа с данным фреймворком и с базой данных впервые. Вот несколько основных блоков кода:

```
    package models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    public String email;
    public String login;
    public String password;
    public boolean isAdmin;

    public User(String email, String login, String password){
        this.email = email;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Вот ещё:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import play.mvc.*;

import java.util.*;

import models.*;
import play.mvc.results.Result;

public class Application extends Controller {
    public static void index() {
        if (params.get("isExit") == "1") {
            session.clear();
            render();
        }

        List<User> users = User.findAll();
        for (User us : users) {
            if (us.email.equals(params.get("email"))) {
                renderArgs.put("avtorization", true);
                break;
            } else renderArgs.put("avtorization", false);
        }
        render(users);
    }

    public static void registration(){
        render();
    }

    public static void newUser() {
        User user = new User(params.get("email"), params.get("login"), params.get("password")).save();
        render(user);
    }
}
```

Буду рад любым подсказкам[image: ![Ошибка]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnloZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

так вроде в браузере написано "No active EntityManager for name default, transaction not started". Вероятнее всего некорректно составлены конфигурационные файлы, подключение к базе данных.